# Flutter How to change containers as panels in java

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to know how to interactively change my containers. I have 4 buttons and I would like each one to change to a different container, keeping the header

this is my actual code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PantallaUsuarioA extends StatefulWidget {
  PantallaUsuarioA({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PantallaUsuarioAState createState() => _PantallaUsuarioAState();
}

class _PantallaUsuarioAState extends State<PantallaUsuarioA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double tamanioPantalla = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double largoPantalla = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: largoPantalla * 0.10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: tamanioPantalla,
              height: 518,
              color: Colors.grey[400],
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: tamanioPantalla,
                          height: 30,
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    shape: Border.all(width: 1),
                                    child: Text('Registrar',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  )),
                              Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    shape: Border.all(width: 1),
                                    child: Text('Eliminar',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  )),
                              Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    shape: Border.all(width: 1),
                                    child: Text('Actualizar',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  )),
                              Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    shape: Border.all(width: 1),
                                    child: Text('Buscar',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    //I want to change this container with the
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                        "i Want to change this container with my other buttons, how can I do that?"),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Photo of the actual program.
[image: actual program]
as you can see I have 4 buttons and I want that every single button as their own container and make a change when an user click on in

Answer (score 0):

you can use visibility /opacity or offstage to switch between widgets on onPressed.
example

```
 bool cont0=true;
    bool cont1=false;
//for your buttons

    Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    shape: Border.all(width: 1),
                                    child: Text('Registrar',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState((){ 
                                      cont0=cont0;
                                        cont1=cont1;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  )),
                              Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    shape: Border.all(width: 1),
                                    child: Text('Eliminar',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                       setState((){ 
                                      cont0=!cont0;
                                        cont1=!cont1;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  )),

//and finally your widgets 

  Container(
                    //I want to change this container with the
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Column(children:<Widget>[
                      Visibility(visible:cont0,child:Text(
                        "i Want to change this container with my other buttons, how can I do that?"),),
                        Visibility(visible:cont1,child:Container(height:100,child:Text(
                        "I am visible"),)),
                    ])
                  )
```